Struggling to map CSV files in QGIS
I am trying to map a CSV file of eastings and northings onto QGIS but am having issues. I have ensured all the correct options are clicked when adding a delimited text layer, including ensuring the correct ESPG option is clicked and the file format is CSV.
The X and Y fields are the correct easting and northing columns, however, when I click apply nothing is showing on the base map.

Can you post a screenshot or something like that of your setting? From the top of my head, when I am having trouble with CSV files it's due to datatypes (e.g., not reading coordinates as decimals).

Please provide a screenshot of you import settings by editing your question.

Dear Jess Nicholson, welcome to GIS SE. I have closed your question as it lacks some vital details like those mentioned by Fjedsen and Erik. Can you be so kind as to provide more details, so people who are eager to help you can proceed with the most efficient answer for you ?

Hi I have just added a screenshot.

Please provide a larger screenshot including the first two rows of the data. Currently it's not clear where you went wrong.

Are you sure your coordinates are in 3857?

I have added a larger screenshot, showing the sample data and easting (GRE) and Northing (GRN) data. I'm assuming the coordiates are in 3857 as thats what the Geometry CRS seems to say.

@JessNicholson, the coordinates in the GRE and GRN fields are not referred to the EPSG:3857 CRS. In order to correctly import the data in QGIS, you need to properly set the Geometry CRS setting, which is the CRS that the coordinates stored in the GRE and GRN fields are referred to.

where are located your points? Your coordinates seems to be UTM

Here is  quick guide to put your Eastings and Northings (British National Grid) into QGIS (3.40 used).
Make sure to set the CRS to British National Grid (OSGB36)


